# Foundation Reveal on AJAX success not working

Tags: php, ajax, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, zurb-reveal

*Attempted to post this on the Foundation forum,  but for some reason it would not post.*

The first code snippet below shows the working code for my form using `data-abide="ajax"`, and the `.on('valid.fndtn.abide',function(){});`. The elements are disabled etc. and the modal opens. When the modal is closed I remain on the page as desired.

I am attempting to now have this use AJAX, where the request will be to a php script handling the data insert, and the element manipulation and modal will happen on success.

The second code snippet shows that attempt, which is not working. When I run this code, the alert fires, but then the page submits, with nothing written to the console, no modal, and the page refreshing. What am I doing wrong?

I have also included partial code (third snippet), for the form and modal.

If anyone has a working example using Foundation, data-abide="ajax" and reveal-modal, where the form is submitted, an AJAX call is made to a PHP script to insert data into the DB, and on success the modal window opens, please provide a sample.

SNIPPET 1 - works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#pledge_btn").attr("disabled", true);

    $(document).foundation({
        abide: {
            validate_on: 'manual',
            patterns: {
                edu_address: /\.edu$/
            }
        }
    });

    $('a.custom-close-reveal-modal').click(function(){
      $('#emailModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
    });

    $('#pledge_form')
    .on('invalid.fndtn.abide', function() {
      $("#pledge_btn").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#terms").prop("checked",false);
      console.log('Not Submitted');
    })
    .on('valid.fndtn.abide', function() {
      $("#pledge_form :input").prop('readonly', true);
      $("#pledge_btn").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#terms").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#sweeps").attr("disabled", true);
      console.log('Submitted: ', data);
      $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    });
});
```

SNIPPET 2 - Does NOT work

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#pledge_btn").attr("disabled", true);

    $(document).foundation({
        abide: {
            validate_on: 'manual',
            patterns: {
                edu_address: /\.edu$/
            }
        }
    });

    $('a.custom-close-reveal-modal').click(function(){
      $('#emailModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
    });

    $('#pledge_form')
    .on('invalid.fndtn.abide', function() {
      $("#pledge_btn").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#terms").prop("checked",false);
      alert("Form NOT submitted");
    })
    .on('valid.fndtn.abide', function() {
        var lname = $("#lName").val();

        var dataString = 'lname=' + lname;

      alert("Form submitted");
      $.ajax({
        url     : create_pledge.php,
        type    : $(this).attr('method'),
        data    : dataString,
        success : function( data ) {
          $("#pledge_form :input").prop('readonly', true);
          $("#pledge_btn").attr("disabled", true);
          $("#terms").attr("disabled", true);
          $("#sweeps").attr("disabled", true);
          console.log('Submitted: ', data);
          $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
        },
        error   : function( data, xhr, err ) {
          console.log('Oops: ', data, xhr , err);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

PARTIAL FORM and MODAL Code

```
    <div class="row pledge-row">
  <form data-abide="ajax" id="pledge_form" method="post" name="pledge_form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 medium-12 columns">
        <label class="pledge-label">First Name*</label>
        <input id="fName" type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"/>
       <small class="error">First Name is required</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 medium-12 columns">
        <label class="pledge-label">Last Name*</label>
        <input id="lName" type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"/>
       <small class="error">Last Name is required</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 medium-12 columns">
          <label class="pledge-label">Email*</label>
          <input id="email" type="email"  required style="margin:0 0 5px 0 !important;"/>             
          <small class="error">.edu email address is required</small>
          <span id="email-result"></span>
          <div class="valid-email">(must be a properly formatted .edu email)</div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- CODE REMOVED FOR THIS POST -->
  </form>
</div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
        <h2 id="modalTitle">Thanks for pledging.</h2>
        <p>please check your email for our confirmation/validation email.</p>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. I needed to have the ajax request in the submit, not the valid event.

So this works:

```
        $('#pledge_form')
    .on('invalid.fndtn.abide', function() {
      $("#pledge_btn").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#terms").prop("checked",false);
      // alert("Form NOT submitted");
    })
    .on('valid.fndtn.abide', function() {
      // alert("Form submitted");
      console.log('VALID');
    })
    .on('submit', function(e) {
        var ajaxObj = $.ajax({
          url   : 'create_pledge.php',
          type    : $(this).attr('method'),
          data    : $(this).serialize(),
          success : function( ) {
            $("#pledge_form :input").prop('readonly', true);
            $("#pledge_btn").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#terms").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#sweeps").attr("disabled", true);
            console.log('Submitted');
            $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
          },
          error   : function( xhr, err ) {
            console.log('Oops: ', xhr , err);
          },
          complete: function(){
              console.log('COMPLETE');
          }
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too with fancybox and ajax check before submit.

This is my solution that works for sure

```
<form id="my_form" action="...." method="POST" class="popup" data-abide="ajax">
<input type="text" name="check_this_field_with_ajax" id="check_this_field_with_ajax">
....

</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="..../js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="..../js/foundation/foundation.abide.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#my_form')
    .on('invalid.fndtn.abide', function() {
        console.log('NOT Submitted');
    })
    .on('valid.fndtn.abide', function() {
      console.log('VALID');
    })
    .on('submit', function(e) {
        var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "....",
            data: {xxx: yyy},
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
        });

        ....

        ajaxRequest.done(function() {
            if (ok) {
                $('#check_this_field_with_ajax').parent().removeClass('error');
                $('#my_form').attr({'submit_this_form': 'yes'});
                $(document).foundation('abide', 'reflow');
                $('#my_form').trigger('submit.fndtn.abide');
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Now go to in foundation.abide.js, search line "`validate : function (els, e, is_ajax) {`" and add:

```
if (
    is_ajax &&
    form.attr('submit_this_form') === 'yes'
    ) {
    return true;
  }
```

before

```
if (is_ajax) {
    return false;
  }
```